# kubelet error：failed to update node lease

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet, kube-apiserver

I setup my kubernetes cluster by kubeadm. at the last step. I need join my nodes to the master. So i copy the join command to the node to exec it and whitout err. Then i back to master to exec "kubectl get nodes". there just a master node and without worker node. So i check the worker node's kubelet log and it show the err like this:

`2月 16 15:51:44 localhost.localdomain kubelet[938]: E0216 15:51:44.608258     938 controller.go:177] failed to update node lease, error: Operation cannot be fulfilled on leases.coordination.k8s.io "localhost.localdomain": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again`
I have no ideal to how to solve it. 
by the way, i have two question, this is one of it. Another is about kube-apiserver: [kubernetes v1.16.2 write: broken out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172489/kubernetes-v1-16-2-write-broken-out?noredirect=1#comment106432160_60172489]) I still haven't solved it
here is the main step i setup the cluster

> ```
> setenforce 0
> sed -i "s/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/g" /etc/selinux/config
>
> systemctl stop firewalld && systemctl disable firewalld
> iptables -F && iptables -X && iptables -F -t nat && iptables -X -t nat && iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
>
> swapoff -a
> sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab
>
> modprobe br_netfilter
> modprobe -- ip_vs
> modprobe -- ip_vs_rr
> modprobe -- ip_vs_wrr
> modprobe -- ip_vs_sh
> modprobe -- nf_conntrack_ipv4
> sysctl -p
>
> cat << EOF | tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
> EOF
> sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
>
> yum install -y epel-release conntrack ipvsadm ipset jq sysstat curl iptables libseccomp  unzip lrzsz
> yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2  ntp ntpdate
>
> ntpdate ntp1.aliyun.com
>
> yum install docker-ce -y
> yum -y install  kubelet-1.17.0 kubeadm-1.17.0 kubectl-1.17.0  kubernetes-cni
>
> systemctl enable docker
> systemctl enable kubelet.service
> systemctl start docker
> systemctl start kubelet
>
> kubeadm config images list
>
> kubeadm config print init-defaults > kubeadm.conf
>
> kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=v1.17.0 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.5.150
>
> mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
> sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
> sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
>
> then copy this to node to exec
> kubeadm join 172.16.5.150:6443 --token 2yj4eu.lhdrdks0dykao9in \
>     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:8563b0c50c48e563cdd4ac4380206133535df8a020bc2a949ff66b5aa7722ea7
> ```

```
[root@localhost calico]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5b644bc49c-8ht2m   1/1     Running            0          82m   192.168.102.134   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-4887h                          1/1     Running            0          82m   172.16.5.152      localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-9pjbp                   1/1     Running            0          9h    192.168.102.133   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-mlrdt                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   17         9h    192.168.102.132   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-6fqwk                           1/1     Running            0          9h    172.16.5.151      localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
[root@localhost calico]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5b644bc49c-8ht2m   0/1     Running            1          82m   192.168.102.137   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-4887h                          1/1     Running            0          82m   172.16.5.159      localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-9pjbp                   1/1     Running            16         9h    192.168.102.136   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-mlrdt                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   15         9h    192.168.102.135   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-6fqwk                           1/1     Running            0          9h    172.16.5.151      localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
[root@localhost calico]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
localhost.localdomain   Ready    master   9h    v1.17.0
[root@localhost calico]#
```

Comment: output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system? Also can you paste the join command that you ran ? At the end did you see a message "Node join complete" ?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu here is the output and the join command
[root@localhost .kube]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-9pjbp   0/1     Pending   0          3h38m
coredns-6955765f44-mlrdt   0/1     Pending   0          3h38m
kube-proxy-6fqwk           1/1     Running   0          3h38m
[root@localhost .kube]#
kubeadm join 172.16.5.150:6443 --token lkgzrz.i8z7i8vkcehlk4cs     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:641dfd5e25022152145e34ea0aeb4816ceb9d9c66c9e398145b55287116cafc9

Comment: Next to the previous one.  when i exec the join command on the worker  node. the output is: ```Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...

This node has joined the cluster:
* Certificate signing request was sent to apiserver and a response was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the control-plane to see this node join the cluster.``` this is the last log of the output

Comment: why don't you add above details in the question itself with proper formatting

Comment: kube-system namespace should have few more pods for api sever, controller, scheduler etc.can you provide the output of kubectl get componentstatuses. Also which docs specifically you followed ?

Comment: @ Arghya Sadhu. sorry about the format. I am learing how to format the question and comment. 
[root@localhost .kube]# kubectl get componentstatuses
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR <br/>
scheduler            Healthy   ok  <br/>                
controller-manager   Healthy   ok   <br/>               
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}<br/>
I am in china. And in china. for the reason of the ISP Block.i can't visit google directly. So  i follow the docs of the chinese docs. if necessary. i can paste the main step.

Comment: yes provide the main steps...are you in public cloud or on Prem bare metal?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu The comment limits the w ord count. and I am not good at format on stackoverflow. So may i get your email and send to your emai or here is my gmail: yinkaicool@gmail.com

Comment: You can edit your question and add the steps.

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu you can see in the question now

Comment: You need to install a pod network add on.Did you install a pod network add on? kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml

Comment: @ Arghya Sadhu I  install calico now. And the master is ready now. but i still can't get the worker nodes   on master by command "kubectl get nodes"

Comment: Did you run the join command again ? Can you run it and what error you get ?

Comment: yes i run "kubeadm reset" on the worker node. then i exec the join command again. the output is as same as before like this: ``` [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet [kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap... This node has joined the cluster: * Certificate signing request was sent to apiserver and a response was received. * The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details. Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the control-plane to see this node join the cluster. ``` this is the last log of the output

Comment: And kubelet logs from both worker and master node? Also what pods you see kubectl get pods -n Kube-system

Comment: @ Arghya Sadhu.There is interesting. I run "docker ps" on the worker node and found that the calico 
component container has been dispatch to he worker node and is running up.

Comment: @ Arghya Sadhu I paste the output on the question. you can see there.

Comment: kubelet logs from worker and master both

Comment: update the question with the following details: exact `kubeadm init` command you issued, exact `kubeadm join` you issued, also, sicne coredns is failing, `kubectl describe pod <failing coredns pod name>` and `kubectl logs <failing coredns pod name>`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on both master and the node, `host <dns of the master node>` from the node machine.

Comment: @morgwai thanks.it will take your suggestion.

Comment: @Esc does this issue was the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305724/service-kube-dns-is-invalid-spec-clusterip-invalid-value-10-10-0-10-fiel ?Or it's diffrent and still occurs?

Comment: @Esc Could you please answer the question above?

Comment: @Esc Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Comment: Is this issue is resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as solution and accept it.